# Is there no convenience method for !nil?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I think I would see my code better if I would ask myself `object.not_nil?` vs `!object.nil?`. So my question: Is there really no convenience method for !nil? to sugar things up? Is it in front of my eyes and I cannot see it or am I just missing an important point?

Comment: the thing is: 99% of the time you don't need `nil?` at all. `if obj.nil?` can always be written as `if obj` unless you want to tell `nil` from `false` (not very common).

Comment: obviously I meant `if !obj.nil?` -> `if obj`. Note that in Ruby only falsy values are `nil` and `false`, everything else is true.

Comment: Though sometimes object.nil? might be more human-readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
not object.nil?
```

But the easier thing to do would be to check for the "truthiness" of by testing the variable itself. Since `nil` is implicitly `false` you can just check `object`.

Comment: Thank you! That does make a lot of sense :)

Comment: "not object.nil?" is not always better choice over "!object.nil", in some statements "not" binds too loosely to the following expression.

Answer (score 4):

You can introduce the sugar at an upper level. Instead of:

```ruby
if not object.nil?
```

you can write:

```ruby
unless object.nil?
```

Answer (score 3):

- What about this ?

  ```
  if object
    # sth
  end
  ```

  It is not the same as it will not be executed if `object` is false but depending on you code, it could be better.
- Another solution (which is not the same either), as you tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails-3` : using `present?` which will not execute the block for `[]` or `{}` unlike `!object.nil?`.
- Again another one depending of the case : using `unless` which won't be really nice if your condition is more complex (with `&&` and/or `||`).
- If your condition is of this form :

  ```
   if !object.nil? && object.something?
     # sth
   end
  ```

  You can use `try`, as you are using Rails, like this :

  ```
  if object.try(:something?)
    # sth
  end
  ```
- In all the other cases, `!object.nil?` or `not object.nil?` stays the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 2):

When convenience around #nil? is discussed, Activesupport's methods #blank? and #present? shouldn't be forgotten either.

Answer (score 2):

Not that you'd necessarily want to, but you can introduce `not_nil?` yourself:

```
class Object
    def not_nil?
        !self.nil?
    end
end
```

then you can do things like:

`nil.not_nil?`
`==> false`

`3.not_nil?`
`==> true`

`a = []`
`a.not_nil?`
`==> true`